# Can assosiated addresses be generated on an account with no SOL on it?

Tags: spl-token, wallet, associated-token-account, spl-associated-token-account

Let's say, I've generated 1000 accounts manually, via code. I also want to generate USDT and USDC addresses for each of them. Then I'll give them to the users of my service for them to send USDT and USDC.

Will USDT and USDC arrive with no issue to each wallet?

It's unknown whether a user will use a wallet, or which one, to send out USDT or USDC. I'm aware that each user will have to have some SOL on his original wallet to cover the cost of a TX as well as creating an assossiated address of the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the USDT/USDC addresses will not exist (but can be derived) and you will not be able to send tokens to the accounts until they're created.

Comment: who is to create them, and how precisely?

Comment: the person who sends the token has to check if the account exists first. If it's not the case, it has to be done by adding this instruction to the transaction (https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.html), before the instruction which transfers the tokens.

Comment: why can't I create them in advance? Whilst with 0 SOL on the main account

Comment: im not certain, but im pretty sure you will have to create them and deposit rent, this is why Effe2 suggested phantom, it takes care of that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can actually try it by yourself : create a new wallet address in phantom, and send some USDC to it, and check if it works :)
I think the real question is how a wallet will "stay alive" on the blockchain if it's not funded, but i don't have the answer to that, hope someone will

Comment: why do mention Phantom wallet in every other sentence? Phantom this, Phantom that, Phantom this, Phantom that. I'm a developer! My main wallet is always code in Rust and blockkchain explorer!

Comment: if you prefer to code the test instead of using a wallet app, go ahead, you will just spend more time to test something, and as a developer, i value my time, so when i have a solution to achieve the exact same result faster, i use this solution ;)

Comment: yes, I do!!!!!!!!!!!!